# Start application with second screen

Tags: android

I have a question regarding android activity.

I have my first loginscreen(MainActivity) and from there go to Secondscreen, now when I am pressing escape button from the secondscreen I want to close the application(or android home screen) and next time open the application I want to start application with secondscreen.

i tried this code on my second screen but it does not working

```
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE)                                 
    {      

        //My logic here

        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do by doing this?

Comment: u have to activity.finish(); on ur escape button code...

Comment: are you refering to keyboard escape button or you have custom button for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I assume you are trying something like below:

*Frist installation#*

LoginScreen>SecondScreen, when you press escape it will close entire app.

*Second Time#*

When you open app it will start from second screen instead loginScreen.

**Solution**

Phase1#

Store your login info in `database or sharepreference` when first time login has been made, and `finish()` loginscreen while opening second screen.

Phase2#

When you open second time your app, `check your login info`, if it is exists then redirect to second activity else open `loginScreen`.

Answer (score 1):

1. First time when you use the application, Start with LoginScreen,
   then call finish(). Also store a shared preference to know that, the
   application is used atleast once(Logged in)
2. Since you finished the LoginScreen, when you press back button on SecondScreen, you will come to device home, not the LoginScreen.
3. Next time when you want to Start the application, check the sharedPreference whether the user is logged in, and finish the LoginScreen just at the start of onCreate

**LoginScreenActivity:**

```
onCreate(){

//check shared preference if logged in
if(yes){

startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Second.class));
finish();
}else{

//do all the login here then,
//set sharedPreference
startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Second.class));
finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start your second activity at that time finish the existing acitivity with `finish()`

example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This code will finish your current acitivity and when your press back button in second activity then the application gose close.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur suggestion,I tried but the thing is it close the application but when i go back to application it take me to again login page but now i want to open application with the Secondscreen

Answer (score 0):

In log in activity call finish after starting second activity.

```
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Now if u press back it should close the app and when u going to start app again the second activity will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. make your log in activity with "noHistory=true" in android menifest activity definition.

   ```
   <activity android:name="YOUR_FIRST_ACTIVITY"
   android:label="FIRST_ACTIVITY"
   android:noHistory="true" />
   ```
2. You can finish() the first activity at the time of starting second activity.

   ```
   startActivity(SECOND_ACTIVITY_INTENT);
   FIRST_ACTIVITY.this.finish();
   ```

Hope it will help you.